# Finding a solution to congruences modulo $801*1729$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Given $x \equiv 676\pmod{801}$ and $x \equiv 1447\pmod{1729}$. I need to solve for $x$. I think I know how to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to generally solve this sort of problem, but I'm not sure how to efficiently do this with these large numbers.

$1729\pmod{801} \equiv 127 \pmod{801}$ and $801\pmod{1729}$ can't be reduced. So for some integers a and b such that $127*a \equiv 676\pmod{801}$ and $801*b \equiv 1447\pmod{1729}$,

$x = 1729*a+801*b$

I just don't know how to get $a$ and $b$ without endless trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better I know for this sort of problems with large numbers is to go to a linear diophantine equation in two variables which is translation of the two given modular equalities and solving it completely finding out first a particular solution. This way we have
$$x=676+801X=1447+1729Y.................(*)$$
When the coefficients are not large, a particular solution is in general easily found while with large coefficients this problem is less easy but always one can find one. In the case of the equation $(*)$ we find $(X,Y)=(124,57)$ so the general solution has the form
$$\begin{cases}X=124+1729t\\Y=57+801t\end{cases}$$

Consequently $$x=676+801(124+1729t)=100000+1384929t$$
(*the same expression is get taking $x=1447+1729(124+1729t)$ of course*).

Thus the minimal positive solution is $\color{red}{x=100000}$

(*In fact $100000-676=99324=124\cdot801$ and $100000-1447=98553=57\cdot1729$*)

Answer (score 1):

The beginning is some version of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm...

$$ 1729 \cdot 82 - 801 \cdot 177 = 1 $$

$$ 1729 \cdot 82 \equiv 1 \pmod{801}  $$ 
 $$ 1729 \cdot 82 \equiv 0 \pmod{1729}  $$ 
 $$  801 \cdot (-177) \equiv 1 \pmod{1729} $$ 
 $$  801 \cdot (-177) \equiv 0 \pmod{801} $$

What numbers $R,S$ ought we to choose in
$$ 1729 \cdot 82 R - 801 \cdot 177 S \; ? $$

I got a large negative number. You are free to add or subtract any multiple of $801 \cdot 1729 = 1384929$ to get an answer that is positive and smaller than $1384929.$ Comes out clean and obviously intentional.

=================================================================

$$  \gcd( 1729, 801 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 1729 }{ 801 } = 2 +  \frac{ 127 }{ 801 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 801 }{ 127 } = 6 +  \frac{ 39 }{ 127 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 127 }{ 39 } = 3 +  \frac{ 10 }{ 39 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 39 }{ 10 } = 3 +  \frac{ 9 }{ 10 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 10 }{ 9 } = 1 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 9 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 9 }{ 1 } = 9 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
 & & 2 & & 6 & & 3 & & 3 & & 1 & & 9 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 2 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 13 }{ 6 }   & &   \frac{ 41 }{ 19 }   & &   \frac{ 136 }{ 63 }   & &   \frac{ 177 }{ 82 }   & &   \frac{ 1729 }{ 801 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{ccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 2 }{ 1 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  6  \\  
  \frac{ 13 }{ 6 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 41 }{ 19 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 136 }{ 63 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 177 }{ 82 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  9  \\  
  \frac{ 1729 }{ 801 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  0  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 1729 \cdot 82 - 801 \cdot 177 = 1 $$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $801=3^2  \times 89 $ and $1729 =7 \times 13 \times 19 $ and so they are coprime.
Use Euclid's Algorithm to calulate
\begin{eqnarray*}
1729 \times 82 \equiv 1 \pmod{801} \\
801 \times 1552 \equiv 1 \pmod {1729}
\end{eqnarray*}

A solution can be constructed easily by $x=676 \times 1729 \times 82 +1447 \times 801 \times 1552 $. Now reduce this value modulo $ 801 \times 1729$ to get $\color{blue}{100000}$.